# UITableView Custom Cell iPhone Using Swift language

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am trying to assign text in Custom Tableview Cell in Swift language. But It gives error stating "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/333xS.png

Comment: There is a large "i" in your name TableVIew. Is that correct?

Comment: ya, it is correct. In Swift, "DequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" function is not supported other custom function except "func tableView(tableView:UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! " Function

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be an error.check for mistyped identifier in the identifier field.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the line of code in the following UITableView Data Source Method. Your code should look like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell: BlogTableCell! = tableVIew.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BlogTableCell") as! BlogTableCell

}
```